# Optionals and root controller access in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I used this code to get access to the root view controller from within my app delegate.  Here's the question - why do I need to have an exclamation point at the end of the first line, and also at the beginning of the second line (after rootController)?  It seems like I have forced an unwrap of the optional UIViewController that is a property of the UIWindow on two separate lines.  This code works just fine the way it is here.  It also works if I remove the exclamation at the end of the first line and put two exclamation points after rootController on the second line/

```
    let rootController = application.windows[0].rootViewController!
    rootController!.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the `windows` property of `UIApplication` is an array of `AnyObject`. I know it seems a bit weird at first, but basically you can think of the first `!` as force downcasting the `AnyObject` to a `UIViewController?` and then force unwrapping the optional `UIViewController?` to finally get the `UIViewController`.

You can check to see how it won't tell you to put two exclamation points if you force downcast the `windows[0]` first and then do the rest:

```
let rootController = (application.windows[0] as! UIWindow).rootViewController
rootController!.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
```

Your first exclamation point acted as that `as!` when you didn't explicitly cast.

Hope this helps.